# Does the Nullity Theorem hold in fields of characteristic 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, involutions

I'm playing around with involutory ($M^2 = I$) matrices over finite fields with characteristic 2 ($\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$).
I came across the [nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullity_theorem), which seems very useful to check if submatrices are (non)singular. It basically states (as far as I understand it), that the nullity of a submatrix in $M$ is equal to the complementary submatrix of the inverse ($M^{-1}$).

Out of caution I routinely check my assumptions and try to find counterexamples.
I checked the 4x4 matrices for $m=6$ and found one which seems to contradict the theorem:

(sagemath code)

```
G=GF(2**6, repr='int')
a=G(58.bits())
b=G(59.bits())
c=G(62.bits())
d=G(63.bits())
M=matrix(4,4,[b,a,d,c,d,c,a,d,d,d,c,a,d,d,d,b])
print(M)
# [59 58 63 62]
# [63 62 58 63]
# [63 63 62 58]
# [63 63 63 59]

print(M*M)
# [1 0 0 0]
# [0 1 0 0]
# [0 0 1 0]
# [0 0 0 1]

import itertools
for d in [2,3]:
    for p1 in itertools.combinations(range(4), d):
        for p2 in itertools.combinations(range(4), d):
            S=M.matrix_from_rows_and_columns(p1, p2)
            if S.determinant() == 0:
                print('det', p1, p2)
            if S.nullity() != 0:
                print('nul', p1, p2)
# det (2, 3) (0, 1)
# nul (2, 3) (0, 1)

print(M.matrix_from_rows_and_columns((2,3), (0,1)))
# [63 63]
# [63 63]
```

As you can see, the matrix $M$ is clearly involutory, so $M = M^{-1}$, but it also has one obviously singular submatrix.

In addition, it ONLY contains this one singular and nullity non-zero submatrix!

According to the nullity theorem, I would expect a second singular submatrix, as there should be a complementary submatrix in the inverse of $M$.

I checked various sources, incl. the original papers, but found no obvious reason, the theorem should not work over special fields.

So my questions are:

- Is there a problem/error in the nullity theorem?
- If not, what is the reason it does not work over $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$?
- Is there something (e.g. additional constraints) to make it work over $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$?

Comment: In the future, it would be better to avoid asking whether a well established theorem is incorrect. The likelihood that you are not correct is very high.

Comment: @KBS I disagree with your advice, the way this question is posed is totally fine, the questions are quite reasonable, and the OP doesn't claim anything overexaggerated. Especially given how many well established results actually don't hold in characteristic two this seem a natural question to have.

Comment: @AlexJBest The title fails to represent or capture any of what you say. A much better title would have been "Does the rank nullity theorem hold in fields of characteristic 2?", which is dramatically different. The current title suggests that the theorem may actually not be a theorem since the proof might be incorrect.

Comment: @KBS Nothing to do with the rank-nullity theorem!

Comment: @TedShifrin that does not really matter. It is not the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything seems ok with your computations. The theorem doesn't forbid a submatrix to be it's own complementary submatrix. In fact, exactly the case you described is covered in the wiki article as $\operatorname{nullity} C = \operatorname{nullity} G$.

Comment: Ok, but then the last paragraph on the wiki page is wrong. it essentially states, that the complementary submatrix would be F, not G!

Comment: @DasArchive Nope, it actually isn't! Follow carefully: your submatrix spans rows $\{i_1=2,i_2=3\}$ and columns $\{j_1=0, j_2=1\}$, then the complement submatrix has rows $\{0, 1, 2, 3\} \setminus \{j_1, j_2\}$ (**not** $\{i_1, i_2\}$!) which equals $\{2, 3\}$, and similarly it spans columns $\{0, 1, 2, 3\} \setminus \{i_1, i_2\} = \{0, 1\}$, which equals the original submatrix.

Answer (score 2):

The complementary block of the one you mention is the block itself in that case as $M^2=I$. Therefore, there is no contradiction.